# How can I use GeoFire and Firebase to query for documents within a certain location?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofire, geofirestore

I'm basically just asking about how to implement **GeoFire** here. I'm using the **Android Java library**, and I've achieved so much as being able to attach **GeoPoints** to each of my documents, but now I'd like to query for them and get a set of documents that are within a certain radius of in this case the user.

I'm not sure how to attack this, the furthers I've gotten is simply instantiating the GeoFire Query.

That's this line here:

```
 GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(new GeoPoint(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]), 0.6);
```

After creating this query, I'm not sure what to do next.

Any insight on the next steps of this implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you review the documentation? It shows you how to handle the results of a query.  https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android

Comment: Doug, Looks like that solved my question perfectly, thank you. I'd seen that documentation before, but it wasn't clear to me how the OnKeyEntered method would show the document that fit the location query... This is because GeoFire's  structure (or layout? not sure how to say it Im not a programmer) breaks from the rest of the FireBase query's where you would typically add an on success listener and wait for the document to show up in a method there.

Apologize for the word soup, but what I'm trying to say is that GeoFire queries look different than other Firebase queries and it confused me.